# How to customize woocommerce plugin using php code?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am beginner in woocommerce. I want to kno about woocommerce plugin that how can I customize a woocommerce product?
For example:

```
<img src="<!--<?php Product Image ?>-->">    
<h4><!--<?php Product Name ?>--></h4>
<p><!--<?php Product Description ?>--></p>
<span><!--<?php Product Price ?>--></span>
```

How can I get product details and put it into my html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do it is overriding the plugins templates within you child theme folder.

You'll find some directions in these pages 
[Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
and 
[Template files - v3.0.0](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/release/3.0/templates)